# Excel VBA Conditional Text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In VBA is there a way to add to a cell if another cell contains any text?

Ex:

FOREACH Cell in Column F that contains text

Write "ASSIGNED" in Column G

IF Cell F is Blank, Skip Cell

I know there is a formula for this ["=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(""*"",RC[-1],6),""ASSIGNED""),"""")"], but the application I am importing this file into does not accept workbooks containing formulas.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In VBA just loop through the range, like (psuedo code): `For each cel in Range("F2:F1000") // if cel.value <> "" then cel.offset(0,1).Value = "ASSIGNED" // end if` ? or maybe use `IsEmpty()`?  A quick thought - if your import doesn't accept formulas, it accepts macros??  You could always use your formula, then copy/paste values over it, thus removing the formulas...I'd highly doubt it'll accept VBA if formulas are already off the table.

Comment: why not run the formula and copy and paste the values as values, range.value=range.value?

Comment: The reason why the VBA code will work is because it is run from my PERSONAL.xlsb instead of the Exported Workbook. The application I am importing these files in to, will not except a Workbook that contains VBA or Formulas. I will try coping the values from the formula, but I though it would be better to have a VBA routine that is built into my Export Macro in my PERSONAL Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Workbooks("My Tracker").Sheets(4).Range("F1:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each Cell In rng
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "ASSIGNED"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```